# Sed replace in html file

Tags: sed

How could I append 'index.html' to all links in a html file that do not end with that word ?

So that, for example, `href="http://mysite/"` would become `href="http://mysite/index.html"`.

Comment: Do you expect there to be a `"` at the end of every link?

Comment: No, I just expect it to be a link, which is what I guess makes for a complicated regex.

Comment: But you would expect the link to end in `/` ? I'm looking for anything that can be used as the condition to say "this is the link, and there was no '/index.html' ". Usually regex / sed is really the wrong tool for this kind of thing unless you have a particularly well formed file; the "general case" needs HTML parsing libraries (things like BeautifulSoup in Python work great).

Comment: Well yes then, to start with, we can assume that the link ends with /, and then I'll see if I have any broken links.

Comment: A mantadory link to [The Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/45249).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a sed expert, but think this works:

```
sed -e "s_\"\(http://[^\"]*\)/index.html\"_\"\1\"_g" \
    -e "s_\"\(http://[^\"]*[^/]\)/*\"_\"\1/index.html\"_g"
```

The first replacement finds URLS already ending in `/index.html` and deletes this ending.

The second replacement adds the `/index.html` as required.  It deals with cases that end in `/` and also those that don't.

More than one version of sed exists.  I'm using the one that comes in XCode for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
echo 'href="http://mysite/"' | awk '/http/ {sub(/\/\"/,"/index.html\"")}1'
href="http://mysite/index.html"
```

```
echo 'href="http://www.google.com/"' | awk '/http/ {sub(/\/\"/,"/index.html\"")}1'
href="http://www.google.com/index.html"
```

Comment: if it is in an html file, there is other part that could have a string with /" so you need to filter a bit

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Added test for `http`

Answer (score 0):

for href ending with `/`

```
sed '\|href="http://.*/| s||\1index.html' YourFile
```

if there is folder ref without ending /, you should specifie what is consider as a file or not (like last name with a dot inside for file, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In general this is an almost unsolvable problem. If your html is "reasonably well behaved", the following expression searches for things that "look a lot like a URL"; you can see it at work at http://regex101.com/r/bZ9mR8 (this shows the search and replace for several examples; it should work for most others)

```
((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/{2})(?:(?:[0-9a-z_@-]+\.)+(?:[0-9a-z]){2,4})?(?:(?:\/(?:[~0-9a-z\#\+\%\@\.\/_-]+))?\/)*(?=\s|\"))(\/)?(index\.html?)?
```

The result of the above match should be replaced with

```
\1index.html
```

Unfortunately this requires regex wizardry that is well beyond the rather pedestrian capabilities of `sed`, so you will have to [unleash the power of `perl`](http://www.atrixnet.com/in-line-search-and-replace-in-files-with-real-perl-regular-expressions/), as follows:

```
perl -p -e '((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/{2})(?:(?:[0-9a-z_@-]+\.)+(?:[0-9a-z]){2,4})?(?:(?:\/(?:[~0-9a-z\#\+\%\@\.\/_-]+))?\/)*(?=\s|\"))(\/)?(index\.html?)?/\index.html/gi'
```

It looks a bit daunting, I know. But it works. The only problem - if a link ends in `/`, it will add `/index.html`. You could easily take the output of the above and process it with

```
sed 's/\/\/index.html/\/index.html/g'
```

To replace a double-backslash-before-index.html with a single backslash...

Some examples (several more given in the link above)

```
http://www.index.com/                        add /index.html
http://ex.com/a/b/"                          add /index.html
http://www.example.com                       add /index.html
http://www.example.com/something             do nothing
http://www.example.com/something/            add /index.html 
http://www.example.com/something/index.html  do nothing
```